# Drag and drop a shape

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm building a Flash app that has some geometric objects.
That part is working.

After drawing a rectangle with the mouse, I want to drag and drop it.
How can I do that?

```
var diktemporaryDrawing:Shape = new Shape();
addChild(diktemporaryDrawing);
diktemporaryDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x666666, 1);

var dikmyDrawing:Shape = new Shape();
addChild(dikmyDrawing);
dikmyDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000, 1);

var mouseHolding:Boolean = false;
var clickedX:Number;
var clickedY:Number;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dikDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dikUp);

function dikDown(MouseEvent):void {
    mouseHolding = true;
    clickedX = mouseX;
    clickedY = mouseY
}

function dikUp(MouseEvent):void {
    mouseHolding = false;
    //myDrawing.graphics.beginFill(0x222222, 0.5);
    dikmyDrawing.graphics.drawRect(clickedX, clickedY, mouseX-clickedX, mouseY-clickedY);
    //myDrawing.graphics.endFill();
    dikclearTemp()
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dikMove);

function dikMove(MouseEvent):void {
    if (mouseHolding) {
        dikclearTemp();
        diktemporaryDrawing.graphics.drawRect(clickedX, clickedY, mouseX-clickedX, mouseY-clickedY)
    }
}

function dikclearTemp():void {
    diktemporaryDrawing.graphics.clear();
    diktemporaryDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x666666, 1)
}
```

Comment: Make your shape a `Sprite`, then it will get all the mouse functionality/events,   including `startDrag()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, *"[Shape](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Shape.html#methodSummary) objects consume less memory than Sprite objects that contain the same graphics. However, a **Sprite object supports user input** events, while a **Shape object does not**."*

Secondly, any class capable of receiving user input (i.e. mouse interactions) has to be a descendant of [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html) class, which Shape class is not. (Inheritance: Shape→DisplayObject→EventDispatcher→Inheritance→Object)

The most basic interactive class there is is [Sprite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html). It is capable of receiving user input (clicks and mouse movements for your purpose). So, you have to create a sprite **for each rectangle you draw**, to be able to drag them separately.

Basically, there are two ways of dragging things: using [startDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag%28%29) and [stopDrag()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#stopDrag%28%29) methods, which are defined on the Sprite class, or just moving an object to match mouse position in MOUSE_MOVE or ENTER_FRAME handler. I'm demonstrating the latter, since it doesn't employ changing your code much.

```
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.display.Sprite;

var diktemporaryDrawing:Shape = new Shape();
diktemporaryDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x666666, 1);

var dikmyDrawing:Sprite = new Sprite();

addChild(dikmyDrawing);
addChild(diktemporaryDrawing); // drawing layer should be above 


var mouseHolding:Boolean = false;
var clickedX:Number;
var clickedY:Number;
var draggingRect:Sprite;

function dikDown(MouseEvent):void {  
  mouseHolding = true;

  var children:Array = dikmyDrawing.getObjectsUnderPoint(new Point(mouseX, mouseY));
  if (children.length > 0) {
    // looks like we clicked some rectangle,
    // starting to drag topmost child.
    draggingRect = children[children.length-1];
    // remember offset between rect center and mouse coordinates,
    // so we don't displace rectangle when dragging
    clickedX = mouseX-draggingRect.x;
    clickedY = mouseY-draggingRect.y;    
  } else {
    // we clicked empty space, starting to draw
    clickedX = mouseX;
    clickedY = mouseY
  }
}

function dikUp(MouseEvent):void {
  mouseHolding = false;

  if (draggingRect == null) {
    // end of drawing new rect
    var dx:Number = mouseX-clickedX;
    var dy:Number = mouseY-clickedY;
    if (Math.abs(dx) > 0 && Math.abs(dy) > 0) {
      // ***
      // new sprite for each rectangle
      var newRect:Sprite = new Sprite();
      newRect.x = clickedX;
      newRect.y = clickedY;
      newRect.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000, 1);
      newRect.graphics.beginFill(0, 0);
      newRect.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, dx, dy);
      newRect.graphics.endFill();
      dikmyDrawing.addChild(newRect);  
      // ***    
    }
    dikclearTemp()
  } else {
    // end of dragging a rectangle
    draggingRect = null;
  }
}

function dikMove(MouseEvent):void {
  if (mouseHolding) {
    if (draggingRect == null) {
      // drawing
      dikclearTemp();
      diktemporaryDrawing.graphics.drawRect(clickedX, clickedY, mouseX-clickedX, mouseY-clickedY)
    } else {
      // dragging
      draggingRect.x = mouseX - clickedX;
      draggingRect.y = mouseY - clickedY;
    }
  }
}

function dikclearTemp():void {
  diktemporaryDrawing.graphics.clear();
  diktemporaryDrawing.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x666666, 1)
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dikDown);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dikUp);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dikMove);
```

Comment: Thanks every body. Thanks very much Nox Noctis. it was just the way i wanted it.

Comment: I am math teacher. Türkiye(Turkey)'s high school. I am improving a simple program for smart board. It's name "Soru Çöz". https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8-x0sIpJBHEb0sxRGFXZ3NFY0k  After your helps it will be better. Again thanks.

Comment: @TancotCossin Good to hear it helped! I can see you are new here, so I'd mention that there is a check mark to the left of every answer, so you can accept the answer that helped the most.

Comment: I have got clear_btn but it doesn't clear the rectangles. How can i clear? clear_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearF);

function clearF(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dikDown);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dikUp);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dikMove);

    dikmyDrawing.graphics.clear();
   
}

Comment: You have to remove all created sprites from `dikmyDrawing`. So, you have to iterate all children and remove them like this: `while(dikmyDrawing.numChildren > 0) {dikmyDrawing.removeChildAt(0);}`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you need to move an object to a position, you can use `startDrag` functionality which is mentioned [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag()).

Your example doesn't move an object, it just draws a line to a given position.

After drawing an object like you did on your example, you can attach MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN and MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP to the shape you have drawn.

```
shape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
shape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
```

In the onMouseDown handler, you can startDrag like

```
function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
     shape.startDrag();
}
```

If you do not want to use startDrag function, you can also store initial shape position in `onMouseDown` function and move by taking differences between the current position and the start position in `onMouseMove` function.

**Edit for @TancotCossin:**

Let's say you are creating rectangles (sprites or movie clips) and adding them to the stage like the following.

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    sprite.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
    addChild(sprite);

}

function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var clickedSprite:Sprite = event.target as Sprite; // or whatever movieclip you are adding
    trace("Selected " + clickedSprite);
}
```

Comment: Not going to work.   The object needs to be or extend Sprite,  which Shape does not.  So it will not dispatch mouse events or have the start/stopDrag methods.  That being said, simply replacing `Shape` with `Sprite` would suffice, as Sprite has a graphics property just like Shape does

Comment: I am drawing a lot of rectangle (using my code) . After how can I select any one clicking mouse?

Comment: You can attach each of them those listeners and you can access those rectangles with event.target